# the value for my new input field is not saved

Tags: php, zend-framework3

I would like to add the new field 'pokemon' (text field) to my entity 'user' 
To do that, I added the property in my class without problem (and with getter/setters)

```
/** @ORM\Column(type="string") */
protected $firstname;

/** @ORM\Column(type="string") */
protected $lastname;

/** @ORM\Column(type="string") */
protected $pokemon;
```

then, for the user add form, I added the pokemon part :

```
class ParticipantForm extends Form
{
    public function __construct($name = null)
    {
        parent::__construct('user');

        $this->setAttribute('class', 'form-horizontal');

        $this->add([
            'name' => 'id',
            'type' => 'Hidden',
        ]);

        $this->add([
            'name'    => 'firstname',
            'type'    => 'Text',
            'options' => [
                'label' => 'First name',
            ],
        ]);

        $this->add([
            'name'    => 'lastname',
            'type'    => 'Text',
            'options' => [
                'label' => 'Last name',
            ],
        ]);

        $this->add([
            'name'    => 'pokemon',
            'type'    => 'Text',
            'options' => [
                'label' => 'pokemon',
            ],
        ]);
```

Then in my form.pthml, I add this code :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"><?=$this->formLabel($form->get('firstname'))?></label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <?=$this->formElement($form->get('firstname'))?>
        <?=$this->formElementErrors($form->get('firstname'))?>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"><?=$this->formLabel($form->get('lastname'))?></label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <?=$this->formElement($form->get('lastname'))?>
        <?=$this->formElementErrors($form->get('lastname'))?>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"><?=$this->formLabel($form->get('pokemon'))?></label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <?=$this->formElement($form->get('pokemon'))?>
        <?=$this->formElementErrors($form->get('pokemon'))?>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my controller, I didn't modify anything and I can modify any other value of my form without any problem. **And of course, I ran the update --force to update my database**

I don't know (or see) where my mistake is so if anybody has an idea to lead my investigation futher. I don't have anymore idea

**EDIT **
Here the UserController code to save my data :

```
public function userFormAction()
{

    /** @var \Zend\Form\Form $form */
    $form = $this->formElementManager->get('user_form');

    $id = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);

    /** @var \Application\Entity\User $user */
    if (0 !== $id) {
        try {
            $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository('Application\Entity\User')->find($id);
            $form->bind($user);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('user/list');
        }
    }

    /** @var Request $request */
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    if (!$request->isPost()) {
        return ['form' => $form];
    }

    $form->setData($request->getPost());

    if (!$form->isValid()) {
        return ['form' => $form];
    }else{
        $user = $form->getData();

        $this->entityManager->persist($user);
        $this->entityManager->flush();

        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('user/list');

    }
}
```

**EDIT**
Setters in protected instead of public.. Problem fixed, I knew it was stupid

Comment: Where do you save form data into the database? Can you share this code?

Comment: I can save/edit correctly names fields but nothing for pokemon field

Comment: You’ve said you’d added getters and setters — how about the `populate` method? I’m assuming you have one, because of `$form->bind($user);`.

Comment: the populate method should be in my Entity User ? 

I just try to add manually a value to pokemon in my database and I can see it properly when I edit the user (but I cannot edit it)

Comment: Apart from getters and setters, do you have any other methods in that entity? If not, probably the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: nothing else than getters/setters. I have no idea where to look, that's my problem ^^

Comment: Try using `var_dump` (or `Zend\Debug\Debug::dump`) on `$user`, `$form->getData()` and `$request->getPost()` to detect where the `pokemon` gets lost. Do you use any input filters?

Comment: No filter, 

I loose the value to the $form->getData() 

I still have it with the $request->getPost() et $form->setData()

Comment: Please delete your question or provide an answer explaining how you fixed it yourself and mark the question as solved.